# export data from mnesia to excel

Tags: excel, erlang, mnesia

I have the table user

```
  -record(person, {id, firstname, lastname}).
```

this table contains this values :

```
    1  francoi     mocci     
    2  test        tes
```

my goal is how can I export this data from mnesia to excel

I know the inverse way meaning transfer data from excel to mnesia

the solution in this case is to converse the excel in csv.file then use this kind of code to parse the csv file :

```
%%% --- csv parser in Erlang. ------
%%% To help process large csv files without loading them into
%%% memory. Similar to the xml parsing technique of SAX

-module(csv).
-compile(export_all).

parse(FilePath,ForEachLine,Opaque)->
    case file:open(FilePath,[read]) of
        {_,S} ->
            start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque);
        Error -> Error
    end.

start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque)->
    Line = io:get_line(S,''),
    case Line of
        eof -> {ok,Opaque};
        "\n" -> start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque);
        "\r\n" -> start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque);
        _ -> 
            NewOpaque = ForEachLine(scanner(clean(clean(Line,10),13)),Opaque),
            start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,NewOpaque)
    end.

scan(InitString,Char,[Head|Buffer]) when Head == Char -> 
    {lists:reverse(InitString),Buffer};
scan(InitString,Char,[Head|Buffer]) when Head =/= Char ->
    scan([Head|InitString],Char,Buffer);
scan(X,_,Buffer) when Buffer == [] -> {done,lists:reverse(X)}.
scanner(Text)-> lists:reverse(traverse_text(Text,[])).

%%traverse_text(Text,Buff)->
  %%  case scan("",$,,Text) of
    %%    {done,SomeText}-> [SomeText|Buff];
 %%       {Value,Rem}-> traverse_text(Rem,[Value|Buff])
   %% end.


traverse_text(Text,Buff)->
    case scan("",$;,Text) of
        {done,SomeText}-> [SomeText|Buff];
        {Value,Rem}-> traverse_text(Rem,[Value|Buff])
    end.


clean(Text,Char)-> 
    string:strip(string:strip(Text,right,Char),left,Char).
```

and this is an example of function to insert data from csv file to mnesia :

```
test()->

    ForEachLine = fun(Line,Buffer)->
   [Id, Firstname, Lastname] = Line,

                                    %% here insert each line to the table mnesia

                                     Buffer end,


 InitialBuffer = [],




 csv:parse("/home/test/Desktop/testt.csv",ForEachLine,InitialBuffer).
```

and this example had no problem

I try with this code :

```
test()->
    F = fun(T) -> mensia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T),
{atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F),
file:write_file("filename.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                 #person{id = F1,firstname = F2,lastname = F3} <- L]).
```

but I have this error :

```
syntax error before : '.'
```

this error is related to this line :

```
#person{id = F1,firstname = F2,lastname = F3} <- L]).
```

**I try to correct my code with :**

```
test()->
    F = fun(T) -> mensia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T),
{atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F),
file:write_file("filename.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                 #person{id = F1,firstname = F2,lastname = F3} <- L])end.
```

but I have now this error :

```
variable 'F' is unbound
```

this error is related to this line :

```
{atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F),
```

**I solved this problem with :**

```
test()->
      F = fun(T) -> mensia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T)end,
{atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F),
file:write_file("filename.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                 #person{id = F1,firstname = F2,lastname = F3} <- L]).
```

**but when I run my function I have this error :**

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {aborted,{{badarity,{#Fun<model.20.69991685>,[]}},
                                                                [{mnesia_tm,apply_fun,3},
                                                                 {mnesia_tm,execute_transaction,5},
                                                                 {model,test,0},
                                                                 {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
                                                                 {shell,exprs,6},
                                                                 {shell,eval_exprs,6},
                                                                 {shell,eval_loop,3}]}}
     in function  model:test/0
```

I try with this code :

```
test()->
      F = fun() -> mensia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],person)end,
{atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F),
file:write_file("filename.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                 #person{id = F1,firstname = F2,lastname = F3} <- L]).
```

but I also have this error :

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {aborted,{undef,[{mensia,foldl,
                                                                               [#Fun<model.21.662230>,[],person]},
                                                                       {mnesia_tm,apply_fun,3},
                                                                       {mnesia_tm,execute_transaction,5},
                                                                       {model,test,0},
                                                                       {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
                                                                       {shell,exprs,6},
                                                                       {shell,eval_exprs,6},
                                                                       {shell,eval_loop,3}]}}
     in function  model:test/0
```

Comment: honestly I know the inverse way meaning transfer data from excel to mnesia , but I didn't find a solution to transfer data from mnesia to excel

Comment: if is not possible to export data from mnesia to excel  , I want to know is it possible to export data from mnesia to sql, if it is possible after export data from mnesia to sql I can export dat from sql to excel

Comment: IF you can export it to textfile, you can use the [XML Excel Standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2003_XML_formats) to create a Excel Sheet .

Comment: first thank you for your answer, but how can we export it to textfile, because I already said I have done the inverse way : transfer data from excel to mnesia but currently I want to export data from mnesia to excel

Comment: heard of `.csv` ? Thats how data is transfered easilly from erlang into excel

Answer (score 1):

You can use the foldl function to create a list and then write this list to a file, using any character as separator (space,comma,tab... depending on the content of your records) and last read the text file with Excel, you will have a popup menu that help you to control the way excel interpret the data.
I think it is better tu use an intermediate list, because writing to a file directly may be long for a database transaction.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I didn't test the line... it should work now.

```
...
F = fun(T) -> mnesia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T) end,
{atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F(mnesia_table)),
file:write_file("filename.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2]) || 
                 #table_record{field1 = F1,field2 = F2} <- L]),
...
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you for your response , but I have an error related to the syntax of my function ,  I have updated my question

Comment: I didn't setup a mnesia database, so I am not able to really test the code I posted. I made some correction and it should work now.

Comment: thank you for your respons, but when I test my function I have this error : Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [rq:1] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
1> model:test().
** exception error: undefined function mensia:foldl/3
     in function  model:test/0
2>

Comment: I want to know if this problem depend of version of erlang or no, now I work with erlang version 13

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `end` in the first line:

```
F = fun(T) -> mensia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T) end,
```

Comment: thank you, but I have now this error : variable 'F' is unbound  , I have updated my code

Comment: Recheck what I wrote you. `end` in the FIRST LINE! Not in the LAST ONE!

Comment: I have an error when I run the function test() ,  I updated my code

Comment: This is because you must use 0-arity function in `mnesia:transaction/1`. Remove `T` argument from `F` and write table name in 3rd parameter of `mnesia:foldl/3`.

Comment: first thank you for your answer ,I followed your advice but I have the same error , I updated my code

Comment: you have a spelling mistake at     F = fun() -> mensia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],person)end, It should be mnesia