# call an undefined function in erlang

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I want to export DATA fom table mnesia to the txt file

I try with this code :

```
exporttxt()->
     F = fun(T) -> mensia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T) end,
{atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F(user)),
file:write_file("test.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                 #user{id = F1,adress = F2,birthday = F3} <- L]).
```

but when I test this function I have this error :

```
Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [rq:1] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
1> model:exporttxt().
** exception error: undefined function mensia:foldl/3
     in function  model:exporttxt/0
2>
```

as you see I work with erlang version 13

**I try now with this code :**

```
exporttxt()->
     F = fun(T) -> mnesia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T) end,
{atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F(user)),
file:write_file("test.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                 #user{id = F1,adress = F2,birthday = F3} <- L]).
```

but I have this error :

```
** exception exit: {aborted,no_transaction}
     in function  mnesia:abort/1
     in call from model:exporttxt/0
```

I try also with :

```
 exporttxt()->
         F = fun(T) -> mnesia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T) end,
    {atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F),
    file:write_file("test.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                     #user{id = F1,adress = F2,birthday = F3} <- L]).
```

but I have this error :

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    {aborted,{{badarity,{#Fun<model.208.16694406>,[]}},
                              [{mnesia_tm,apply_fun,3},
                               {mnesia_tm,execute_transaction,5},
                               {model,exporttxt,0},
                               {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
                               {shell,exprs,6},
                               {shell,eval_exprs,6},
                               {shell,eval_loop,3}]}}
     in function  model:exporttxt/0
```

Comment: And your question is? Could you explain your specific question and code a bit more?

Comment: I want juste to know if the problem of the problem is depend of the version of erlang or no ( the problem is to call the function mensia:foldl )

Comment: Please, to transfer data from erlang applications into excel, consider writing a `.csv` file.

Comment: but how can I write a .csv file, can I change only file:write_file("test.csv",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || ......

Comment: possible duplicate of questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337522/transfer-data-from-mnesia-to-excel-in-erlang and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335898/export-data-from-mnesia-to-excel is not good practice to ask the same question over and over again

Answer (score 2):

It is not the problem with the Erlang version. It is the problem with the statement  `mensia:foldl` spelling is wrong. It should be 
`mnesia:foldl`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but now I have another error, I have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

```
mnesia:transaction(F(user))
```

that is wrong, take a minute and look at it.  mnesia:transaction/1 expect a function, you aren't passing it a function,  you pass whatever the *result* of F(user) is.. (remember erlang uses  strict evaluation, so it evaluates F(user) *before* mnesia:transaction/1).

In your case that call to F(user) fails because it was expected to run inside a transaction.

Comment: thank you for your response , can I make juste mnesia:transaction(F) but when I make this I have an error ,

Comment: I should modify this line : {atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F), as you said (" it was expected to run inside a transaction")