# Transfer data in .txt file in erlang

Tags: erlang

I work in erlang

Now, I have a big problem

I want to have a log from a table mnesia  and this log should be write in excel file

So the goal is write data from table mnesia to the excel file

I think and this is related to some code find in this forum  that the best way is to write .txt file then transfer data from .txt file to excel file

I find this code in this forum in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344434/call-an-undefined-function-in-erlang).

```erlang
exporttxt()->
     F = fun(T) -> mnesia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T) end,
{atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F(user)),
file:write_file("test.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                 #user{id = F1,adress = F2,birthday = F3} <- L]).
```

But this code produces an error

Comment: possible duplicate of [call an undefined function in erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344434/call-an-undefined-function-in-erlang)

Comment: The reason for this error has been explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15351931/113848) in the question you linked to.

Comment: 4th time you ask this using new account

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the problem is clearly explained in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344434/call-an-undefined-function-in-erlang/15351931#15351931) itself. If you want the code then here it is. But please understand before directly jumping into the code.

```
exporttxt()->
    F = fun() -> mnesia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],user) end,
    {atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F),
    file:write_file("test.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                     #user{id = F1,adress = F2,birthday = F3} <- L]).
```

Answer (score 0):

in the subject you mention, I said that I didn't test the code, and of course there was a syntax error.
Here is a code that run.

```
1> ok = mnesia:create_schema([node()]).
ok
2> rd(my_user,{firstname,lastname,age}).
my_user
3> ok =application:start(mnesia).
ok
4> {atomic,ok} = mnesia:create_table(my_user,[{attributes,record_info(fields,my_user)},{disc_copies,[node()]},{type,bag}]).
{atomic,ok}
5> Add_user = fun(Fn,Ln,Ag) ->
5>      F = fun() -> mnesia:write(my_user,#my_user{firstname=Fn,lastname=Ln,age=Ag},write) end,
5>      mnesia:activity(transaction,F)
5> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.18.82930912>
6> ok = Add_user("Georges","Boy",25).
ok
7> ok = Add_user("Joe","Armstrong",52).
ok
8> ok = Add_user("Pascal","Me",55).
ok
9> F = fun(T) -> mnesia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],T) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.82930912>
10> {atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F,[my_user]).
{atomic,[#my_user{firstname = "Pascal",lastname = "Me",
                  age = 55},
         #my_user{firstname = "Joe",lastname = "Armstrong",age = 52},
         #my_user{firstname = "Georges",lastname = "Boy",age = 25}]}
11> ok = file:write_file("test.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || #my_user{firstname = F1, lastname = F2, age = F3} <- L]).
ok
12>
```

you will have in your working directory a file named test.txt containing

```
"Pascal"    "Me"    55
"Joe"   "Armstrong" 52
"Georges"   "Boy"   25
```

and if you open it with excel you will get

[image]

But this is not a code sequence you should use directly.

- line 1 should take place in a code use for the deployment of your application.
- line 2 is a record definition, necessary for the shell to understand the next lines. It should be replaced by a -record(...) in a module or an included file.
- lines 3 and 4 should take place in the init function of one of the higher level supervisor (with some test to check already started application, existing table...)
- line 5 should be in the interface definition of a server
- line 6,7,8 should be generated by a user interface in some client
- and last line 9,10,11 in another interface (for admin?).

**Message to Lost_with_coding and his fellows,**

If I may give you my opinion, you are burning steps. You should focus on mastering the Erlang syntax, the concept of pattern matching and variable bounding... after you should look at more advance construction such as list and binary comprehensions. Take time to look at error messages and use them to solve simple problems. The official Erlang documentation is great for this purpose. I always have it open in my browser and sometimes I also use this link http://erldocs.com/R15B/ when I look for function I don't know.

Next will come higher order functions, error handling, processes, concurrency, OTP... plus the usage of the efficient but not sexy Erlang tools (tv, appmon, debugger...).

I recommend it very often, but use the fantastic Fred Hebert's web site http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ and follow it step by step, rewriting the code, not copy/paste; it really worths the effort.